# Trying to Modify A Local Copy of a Drupal Multisite

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've got all the files and the database for my website on my MAMP htdocs directory.

I'm facing an issue at the moment as the site isn't set up with a 'default' site folder, instead it's set up as 'all' (included as standard) and 'example.com' website domain.

Unfortunately I need to access this, but I'm unable to as it's running from my localhost. I was being entered into a re-direct loop with the install.php file.

I tried changing the 'example.com' folder to 'localhost' on a whim and the website displayed, but the theme data is still searching for resources within 'example.com' folder structure.

I duplicated the 'localhost' file and returned the name of the copy to 'example.com' and the website now displays, but this set up is certainly not ideal as I've kinda botched a workaround.

In an effort to understand how drupal works a little more, could somebody help me here. How do I stop the files looking in the 'example.com' directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the problem lies with Drupal, rather with your own Mamp setup.

If you're not ready to dish out for a copy of Mamp Pro, which would allow you to create various domains without being limited to "localhost", you'll have to look into setting virtual hosts in Apache.

A web search like "Virtual Hosts Mamp tutorials" will help you find relevant tutorials.

After you're able to set a specific domain name, you shouldn't really have any trouble with setting up a local copy of your site.